# Сравнение строк из массива с введенными вручную

Tags: массивы, строки, scanner, equals

Задан массив из 10 готовых слов. Вводим с клавиатуры любое: если оно совпадает со словом из массива - выводим "Слово совпадает со строкой ... ", если не совпадает - "Ошибка". Моя программа работает, но я хочу ее улучшить. Можно ли вместо ответа в виде массива "Ошибка Ошибка ... Слово совпадает со строкой ... Ошибка" вывести один ответ? Например, если есть хоть одно совпадение, пишет просто "Слово совпадает со строкой ... ", если нет - "Ошибка".

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class grammar {

public static void main (String [] args){

    String[] s = {"лист","буква","книга","стол","стул","нога","рука","нить","тонна","нос"};
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++){

        System.out.println(s[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Введите слово: ");
    String name = in.nextLine();

    for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {

        if (s[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {

            System.out.println("Слово совпадает со строкой '"+s[i]+"'");
        }

        else {

            System.out.println("Ошибка");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если найдено совпадение - вывести сообщение и завершить работу программы. А вывод сообщения, что совпадения нет, делать после завершения цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Если слово найдено, незачем проходить дальше по циклу.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class grammar {

public static void main (String [] args){

String[] s = {"лист","буква","книга","стол","стул","нога","рука","нить","тонна","нос"};
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++){

    System.out.println(s[i]);
}

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Введите слово: ");
String name = in.nextLine();
boolean inThisArray = false;
String word = "";
for (int i=0; i<s.length; i++) {

    if (s[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            inThisArray = true;
            word = s[i];
            break;

    }
}
if (inThisArray)
    System.out.println("Слово совпадает со строкой " + word);
else
    System.out.println("Ошибка");
}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Да, думал применить boolean, но не знал, как именно.

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, то один из подходов может выглядеть следующим образом

```
int i = 0;

while ( i < s.length && !s[i].equalsIgnoreCase(name) ) i++;

if ( i != s.length )
{
    System.out.println("Слово совпадает со строкой '"+s[i]+"'");
}
else 
{
    System.out.println("Ошибка");
}
```